# SQL Multiple Insert with one changing parameter

Tags: sql, sql-insert

5 columns, 4 of them are static and 1 of them is changing (the bold one):

```
INSERT INTO sao.feature
(colA, colB, colC, **colD**, colE)
VALUES
('16.11.2021', '149', '79', '**225**', '3')
```

My list of values:

Values:

```
225, 226, 320, 15200, 120, 5, .....
```

How I could execute the insert statement without repeating the statement for each row manually with corrected Column D Values?
Could I provide in SQL MS a List and a loop proceed each value?

My primitive imagination:

```
DECLARE @x AS INT (or Array or something else)
SET @x = 0

List(225, 226, 320, 15200, 120, 5)
    
WHILE x < 100
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sao.feature
(colA, colB, colC, colD, colE)
VALUES
('16.11.2021', '149', '79', x , '3')
SET @x = @x + 1
END
```

Comment: Looping is completely unnecessary. Just do a `INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM`

Comment: Where is your list of values coming from?

Comment: @Stu its from an excel sheet - Ive got just these values in one column like:

225
226
320
....

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just define your list of values using a `values` clause in a CTE and then select from it, hard-coding your other columns:

```
with list as (
    select * from (values
        (225),
        (226),
        (320)
        ........ etc
    )x(v)
)
insert into sao.feature (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE)
select '16.11.2021', '149', '79', v, '3'
from list
```